# Cypress how to get length of text

Tags: javascript, html, cypress, e2e-testing

Lets say I have table which consist of some values. To get the value from specific cell I can use this code to check whether it contains some text:

```
cy.get('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)', {timeout: 15000}).should('have.text', "Ketchup")
```

How can I assert/check if that text has minimum length of 5?

I tried using

```
cy.get('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)', {timeout: 15000}).its('text').should("have.length", 5)
    })
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
cy.get('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)', {
    timeout: 15000
}).invoke('text').then((text) => {
    expect(text.length).to.be.at.least(5)
})
```